# PHP: Laravel how to create model in multiple one-many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, entity-relationship

I have a relationship between three models in my laravel application, `user` model has many `pages` and `pages` has many `keywords`, all of which correspond to three tables on the database with same names. I want to create a `user` and pass along the users `pages` and `keywords` to the pages. I doubt I have any idea how to do it. What I did is below but it does not work, even when I add `keywords` to `$fillable` it throws an exception `no column keywords on pages`

what I did is:

```
        $pages  =   [
            'name' => 'mimi',
            'link' => 'mimi',
            'category' => 'trivial',
            'keywords' => [
                ['name' => 'GGG'], 
                ['name' => 'DDD']
            ]
        ];

        $user->pages()->create($pages);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create the page first, than add the keywords. (not sure if the syntax is correct)

```
$pages  =   [
    'name' => 'mimi',
    'link' => 'mimi',
    'category' => 'trivial'
];

$keywords = ['GGG','DDD'];

$page = $user->pages()->create($pages);

foreach($keywords as $keyword) {
  $page->keywords()->create(['name' => $keyword]);
}
```